# Find the area between the $Ox$ axis, a given function and the function's tangent.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have to find the area between the $Ox$ axis, the function $y = \ln x$ and the tangent of $y$ **which goes through** the origin $O(0, 0)$.

How can I solve this? I don't recognize this as a definite integral so I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The tangent line through the origin is of the form $y=mx$. Suppose the point of tangency on the curve is $P(a,b)$, then $m=\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)\Big|_{x=a}=\frac{1}{a}$. Thus the tangent line is $y=\frac{x}{a}$. Now try to find $a$ and set up the integral:
$$\text{area}=\int_0^{a}\text{line} \, dx -\int_{1}^{a} \text{curve} \, dx$$

Comment: But how can I find $a$?

Comment: @user1502 The point $P$ lies both on the curve and the tangent line. From the line's equation you get that $y=1$ @ $x=a$. This means the point $P$ is $(a,1)$, now plug in this in the curve's equation to get $\ln a =1$, which gives you $a=e$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the tangent line and $y=\ln x$ intersect at the point $(e, 1)$, because the condition $y’=\frac1x=\frac yx$ holds. Also, it is more convenient to integrate the area along the $y$-direction since there is no need to break the integral region.

Then, let $x=ey$ be the tengent line and rewrite the curve in the form $x=e^y$. Thus, the area integral is given by,

$$\int_0^1 (e^y-ey)dy=\frac 12e-1$$

Answer (score 0):

The tangent to the curve which passes through the origin is the tangent at the pointwith abscissa $x=\mathrm e$, and its equation is $\;y=\dfrac x{\mathrm{e}}$. As the logarithm is a concave function, the tangent is above the curve, you have to consider the integral$$\int_1^{\mathrm e}\Bigl(\dfrac x{\mathrm{e}} -\ln x\Bigr)\mathrm dx,$$
which is standard. You should find $\dfrac{\mathrm e} 2$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Because the logarithm is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: @AnuragA: I forgot the $x$-axis! Thank you for reminding me, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: "The tangent to the curve which passes through the origin is the tangent at the point with abscissa $x=e$, and its equation is $y = \dfrac{x} {e} $", I'm interested in how you found that. I don't know how to get to that point.

Comment: Every first year student has done this exercise. Just wite the general equation of the tangent at the point $(x_0,\ln x_0) $: $$y=\frac1{x_0}(x-x_0)+\ln x_0,$$ and write it has no constant term.